# How to keep Mail running and notifying me on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have added facebook app to Windows10 from store, and I get notification in the Action Centre. Great!

I have connected my Gmail and Outlook accounts to Mail.. but no notifications? Even though I set notifications. Is there something non obvious I need to do?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying about this https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549?hl=en

Comment: No, I mean from MAIL app itself. I set the Notifications ON and Show banner... nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to wait a bit before notifications start. It may be due to synchronisation of IMAP.

Mine just started to work after 2 days.